# Почему суффикс -ИМ- в слове движимый

Tags: орфография, причастия

Слова  "движимый, движимость" образованы от глагола 1 спряжения "двигать" (двинуть?), но ведь в таком случае, согласно известному правилу, в этих словах должен быть  суффикс -ем-. Почему же указанные слова нарушают это правило? Может быть, ранее было слово "движить" (ср. "движитель прогресса")? Помогите, коллеги, разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно так - от "движить". Ссылки прислать не могу, не хочется ночью по Интернету блукать, но на лекциях когда-то преподаватель современного русского объяснял именно так.

Answer (score 2):

Даже не копая по сути, могу сказать, что такое - или подобное - слово наверняка было. Иначе невозможно объяснит позиционную мену Г<>Ж.  
Напрямую от "двигать" было бы "двигаемый".

Answer (score 2):

причастие движимый берет свои корни от старославянского глагола движити, вот оттуда и идет орфография этого слова

Answer (score 0):

Все верно: у Розенталя - Голубь.  Движимый (образовано от старого глагола движити).

Answer (score 0):

Движимый --причастие, образованное от устаревшего глагола "движити" 2 спряжения, а не от" двигать". Поэтому это причастие нужно запомнить и писать с "и".

Comment: *Движимый --причастие, образованное от устаревшего глагола "движити"* - это всё так, но тогда Вам надо объяснить, как от такого глагола со значением близким к "беспокоить(ся)" образовался, например, термин, означающий вещественное имущество.

Comment: @shampar, Вы излишне придираетесь.  Ответ по сути, просто слишком краткий.

Comment: Убрал дежурную фразу, хотя пропал мой комментарий, который был (вроде) вначале, примерно такой: зачем давать ответ вдогонку к трём таким же, если один из них был одобрен автором года два назад.

Answer (score -2):

Образование слова я не знаю, но суффикс ИМ пишется, потому что это слово-исключение.